# Fitting signals to slots in Qt

Tags: qt, button, signals-slots

I'm trying to enable a `QPushButton` after another `QPushButton` is clicked and I've run into a problem. The first `QPushButton` can emit a `clicked()` signal while the second `QPushButton` only has slots of the form `setEnabled(bool)` and `setDisabled(bool)`.

Basically, I'm trying to do

```
connect(ui->pbViewVolume,  SIGNAL(clicked()), 
        ui->pbSaveAsImage, SLOT(setEnabled(true)));
```

Since it's not possible to send a signal with fewer parameters than the slot, how can I best do this? The only way I see is to create a public slot for my `MainWindow` like

```
void EnableSaveAsImageButton(){
    ui->pbSaveAsImage->setEnabled(true);
}
```

but I'd rather not fill my `MainWindow` with this sort of rubbish function.

Comment: Note that you cannot give actual parameter values in connects, like that `true` in your example code. You can only give parameter types, like `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to create that slot.
2. You don't need to make that slot public, make it private.
3. This function is not rubbish.

Comment: Good point about making the slot private. OK, perhaps I was too harsh in calling the function rubbish. But it's really unnecessary; since `setEnabled()` and `setDisabled` both exist, it'd be better if neither took any arguments.

Comment: It might be better in your case, but I don't think it would be better in general.

Comment: That'd get a bit verbose if you have the state as bool variable: "if (foo) w->setEnabled(); else w->setDisabled();" Also, a common pattern is to connect toggled(bool) of checkable buttons to setEnabled/setDisabled.